# How to fix a 'damaged app' error message when the app can't be found

Tags: macos, gatekeeper

I have been getting the error message "DeepL” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Bin" on my Macbook (OS: 14.0 (23A344))

I tried searching for the app in Applications/Downloads so I could delete it but it's nowhere to be found. Any suggestions?

Comment: What triggers this message? You've looked in /Applications, and in ~/Downloads, yes?

Comment: Very good clarification @benwiggy I’ll throw up a spotlight specific answer on case that’s all that’s needed here but you may be on to the proper question and Sara knows how to search and just didn’t write about it in the description.

Comment: DeepL is a "translator" app.  You might try [this link from the DeepL help center](https://support.deepl.com/hc/en-us/articles/4407741925778-Desktop-app-doesn-t-work), but they seem pretty lame about un-installing things in macOS.

Comment: Also, updating to the latest version of Sonoma may remove any glitches.

Answer (score 2):

[Spotlight should show you all files with that text](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1008/mac) and then you can [filter by kind if needed with a search constraint](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh15155/mac) or just by selecting the kind ordering in finder column layout.

It’s hard to know your comfort level with spotlight or finder without a screen shot of your search efforts. Could you edit your question a bit to show what you see on your screen when you can’t find that app?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Macbook Ventura. I think removing from Trash did help get rid of the error message in my case, however I am unable now to redownload the Deepl app from their web page and they only let Pro users contact them. The problem may be related to that the default Mac download of Deepl app is for Big Sur as the link contains "bigsur": https://appdownload.deepl.com/macos/bigsur/DeepL.dmg

Answer (score -1):

I faced same problem.
Why don't you try empty Trash?
Removing 'DeepL.app' from Trash didn't work, so I solved this above way.