# "DeepL” is damaged and can’t be opened

Tags: macos

I have been getting the error message

> "DeepL” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Bin

on my iMac (Ventura 13.6.1). There is nothing in downloads or apps and clicking `move to bin` or `cancel` stops it for a few seconds and it reappears. I've tried reinstalling and uninstalling the app but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Potential duplicate - [How to fix a 'damaged app' error message when the app can't be found](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466173/how-to-fix-a-damaged-app-error-message-when-the-app-cant-be-found)

Comment: Did you reinstall from a newly downloaded copy? If so, it's possible that DeepL have made some mistake, like using a lapsed certificate. However, I have the latest version (23.9.159), and that does not flag any errors here.

Comment: The message starting appearing even though I no longer had the app. I then reinsatlled the new version - but the message keeps coming.

Comment: @bmike did you find an answer to this problem?

Comment: Try reinstalling, then throw the app onto [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (Freeware) & see what it finds, rather than just throwing the app itself in the Trash.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck allow DeepL to run in the background in settings > general.

Seems the uninstall is broken

Answer (score 0):

C cleaner seems to have sorted it!